# Why does my Ajax.BeginForm reload the entire page when I have specifically targeted an ID for replacement?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Apologies in advance for the question, but though I found numerous suggestions here, none have worked out for me.  I'm feeling crazy, so...

I have an MVC 3 application that, when it first loads up, displays table with Model data for all users.  That part works fine.  I have two text boxes, one for account ID and another for user that allows me to requery the database for more specific user data.  When I use the submit button, I get the data back but the entire page refreshes and, while I get the form and table back with the correct data, the rest of the page is white.  No graphics I had previously or anything. Another interesting thing is that if i submit the form again, from the white page, with whatever valid parameters, the AJAX DOES work. I'm baffled.

The form looks like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TaskList", "Dispatch", 
       new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "tblBody", 
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { id = "frmTaskList" }))
{
    <table id="tblTaskList" class="tblTaskList"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Ticket ID</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tblBody" class="tblBody">        
            @{for (var ix = 0; ix < Model.Value.Count - 1; ix++)
            { 
                <tr id="@(Model.Value[ix].TicketId)">
                    <td>@Model.Value[ix].TicketId</td>
                    <td>@Model.Value[ix].Created</td>
                    <td>@Model.Value[ix].ContactName</td>
                </tr>        
            }}
        </tbody>       
    </table>    

    <input type="text" id="hidAccId" name="hidAccId" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="hidUserId" name="hidUserId" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnTaskList" value="Submit" />
}
```

Also the scripts I'm using, placed at the top of the page:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Side note: I have tried using @Url.Content instead of the src attribute to no avail.  I've also experimented using the following, again with no different result:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have jQuery and jQuery-ui referenced twice. It's not necessary. The following should be enough:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You obviously should ensure that jquery-1.7.2.min.js is present in the Scripts folder. Out of the box ASP.NET MVC 3 comes only with jQuery 1.5. As far as the Microsoft* scripts are concerned, forget about those, they are no longer used in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Also you don't have a submit button in your form.

This:

```
<input type="button" id="btnTaskList" value="Submit" />
```

should be:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnTaskList" value="Submit" />
```

if you expect a form submission to happen.

Comment: i saw that, i actually pasted things wrong.  I don't have anything included twice, actually.  the jquery 1.7.2 is there.  i'd downloaded it before including it hehe

Comment: Do you have some errors in the console? Did you ensure that all scripts are properly reference in the Network tab and that there are no 404 errors? What happens when you submit the form? Do you see some errors? Do you see the AJAX request being trigerred? Did you notice that I haven't hardcoded the path to those scripts, I have used the `@Url.Content` helper. Did you replace the button with an actual submit button?

Comment: apologies, i didn't submit the javascript i used to submit. document.forms["frmTaskList"].submit();   i'd tried with the submit button, too.  i guess i got so frustrated i tried tons of things that may not have mattered.

Comment: What javascript are you using? That's what the Ajax.BeginForm and the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script does. Don't write any javascript for that. Just use a regular submit button.

Comment: and there was an onclick there, i just edited poorly.  apologies.  the end result is no matter whether i use the submit button or call it programmatically, it doesn't work correctly

Comment: It doesn't work initially when you submit? Or the second time? You haven't provided enough code in your question for me to be able to help you. Ajax.BeginForm should work without any problems with jquery and jquery.unoobtrusive-ajax.

Comment: it doesn't work initially.  it will refresh the entire page and return the entire form back with the correct data.  If i resubmit it from that refreshed page, the AJAX works THEN.

Comment: Do you have javascript errors in the console when loading the page? There oughta be something. Can you send me your project so that I can take a look? I am unable to help you from the information you provide me here and apparently you are unable to debug. If you could send me a narrowed down version of your project illustrating the problem (with all data hardcoded so that I don't have to setup databases and stuff) I would be happy to take a look at tell you what's wrong.

Comment: hehe wife needed me.  That would be great, Darin.  Where should I send it?

Comment: You could either upload it somewhere and send me a link or email me (mail address in my profile).

Comment: i was just modifying a copy for you when i noticed my mistake.  I unintentionally put the ID for the table body vs the table itself when setting the updatetargetID attribute  I'm not sure why it behaved like it did, but it works like a charm now.  Thanks for your help and quick responses.